# Reducing Function Complexity

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, javascript-objects

I'm writing a simple calculator in React. I'm trying to update the state of a component based on which button is clicked (as you would expect). The component's state is as follows:

```
this.state = {
  total: null,
  next: null,
  operation: null,
}
```

Presently, I have one long if/else statement that checks a bunch of scenarios to determine what the appropriate values should be. I'm wondering how I could rewrite this to reduce the complexity of the function:

```
handleClick(buttonName) {
    let { total, next } = this.state;
    const { operation } = this.state;
    let obj;
    const nums = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];
    const syms = ['+', '-', 'X', '/', '%'];
    const equal = '=';
    const reset = 'AC';
    const decimalPoint = '.';

    if (total === null && nums.indexOf(buttonName) >= 0) {
      this.setState({
        total: buttonName,
      });
    } else if (total !== null
      && buttonName === decimalPoint
      && (total.indexOf(decimalPoint) === -1)) {
      this.setState({
        total: total += buttonName,
      });
    } else if (total !== null
      && next !== null
      && buttonName === decimalPoint
      && (next.indexOf(decimalPoint) === -1)) {
      this.setState({
        next: next += buttonName,
      });
    } else if (total !== null
      && operation === null
      && syms.indexOf(buttonName) >= 0) {
      this.setState({
        operation: buttonName,
      });
    } else if (total !== null
      && operation === null
      && nums.indexOf(buttonName) >= 0) {
      this.setState({
        total: total += buttonName,
      });
    } else if (total !== null
      && operation !== null
      && next === null
      && nums.indexOf(buttonName) >= 0) {
      this.setState({
        next: buttonName,
      });
    } else if (total !== null
      && operation !== null
      && next !== null
      && nums.indexOf(buttonName) >= 0) {
      this.setState({
        next: next += buttonName,
      });
    } else if (total !== null
      && operation !== null
      && next !== null
      && ((buttonName === equal) || (buttonName === reset))) {
      obj = method.calculate(this.state, operation);
      this.setState({
        total: obj.total,
        next: obj.next,
        operation: buttonName,
      });
    }
  }
```

PS. the "method.calculate" function is stated in another module.

Comment: Simple, have different handlers for different classes of action (number entry, operation, equals etc). In any case your question might be better on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Didn't know codereview was a thing, tbh. I'll post it there as well, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [reify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314884/what-do-reify-and-reification-mean-in-the-context-of-functional-programmi) the click handler conditions, and then have a utility function select and invoke the relevant handler.

I don't know if this will work in your case because I am not sure if the reference to `state` is constant and whether `setState` is target-dependent, but this serves as an example.

**Edit:** I have investigated how React works, and the precise code below will likely *not* work, but the general approach is sound.

```js
const createHandler = 
    ({ state, setState }) => 
        (buttonName) => handlers.some(({condition, action}) => 
            condition({ buttonName, state: this.state}) && 
            action({buttonName, state, setState}) && 
            true)

const handlers = [ 
    { 
        condition: ({ state: { total }}) => {
            const nums = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
            return (total === null && nums.indexOf(buttonName) >= 0)
        },
        action: ({ buttonName, setState }) => setState({ total: buttonName })
    },
    // ...
];

class MyComponent {
    constructor() {
        this.handle = createHandler({ state: this.state, setState: this.setState })
    }

    handleClick(buttonName) {
        this.handle(buttonName)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In short:

Try to store your conditions values in variables (please try to give them better names)

```
   const check1 = nums.indexOf(buttonName) >= 0
   const check2 = buttonName === decimalPoint
   const check3 = next.indexOf(decimalPoint) === -1)
```

Then, try to reconstruct your statements as nested, using the variables instead of expressions. For instance:

```
    if (total) {
     if (check2 && check3) {
        if (next) {
           this.setState({ next: next += buttonName });
        }
        else {
           this.setState({total: total += buttonName });
        }
     }
     else {
     }
    }
```

This is of-course just a proposal. In your case it will:

- Stop re-calculating expressions over and over again
- Make code more readable and maintainable
- Allow you to collaborate with other developers

And yes.. [Stack Exchange Code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is a thing :)